# Check that Vue.js VNode is text node

Tags: vue.js

What’s the best way to check whether a Vue.js virtual node (VNode), e. g. one that a component has received via `this.$slots`, is a text node or not?

In other words, if a component is used like this –

```html
<MyComponent>
    <template v-slot="a">My text</template>
    <template v-slot="b"><MyOtherComponent/></template>
    <template v-slot="c"><MyOtherComponent v-if="false"></template>
</MyComponent>
```

– then it should only detect `this.$slots.a[0]` as a text node, not `this.$slots.b[0]` or `this.$slots.c[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is this:

```js
function isTextVNode( vnode ) {
    return vnode.text !== undefined && !vnode.isComment;
}
```

TypeScript version, with a type predicate allowing you to access the `text` without it being `undefined`:

```js
function isTextVNode( vnode: VNode ): vnode is { text: string } & VNode {
    return vnode.text !== undefined && !vnode.isComment;
}
```

The check for `isComment` is necessary so that the function will not match empty comment placeholders, as created by `createEmptyVNode()`; however, the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/6390f70c2e4ec7e51cce1d2a4ba35e2d0d328205/src/core/vdom/vnode.js) describes `isComment` as “strictly internal”, so I’d like to know if there’s a solution without relying on this internal property.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the fact that `isComment` is listed as one of the internals, Vue seems to use pretty much the same approach on the [text node checking](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/6390f70c2e4ec7e51cce1d2a4ba35e2d0d328205/src/platforms/web/runtime/components/transition.js#L79), and you're actually pretty close:

```js
const isNotTextNode = (c: VNode) => c.tag || isAsyncPlaceholder(c)
```

Where [`isAsyncPlaceholder`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/helpers/is-async-placeholder.js) is a function that looks for this `isComment` state internally, and luckily it's also exported.

```js
export function isAsyncPlaceholder (node: VNode): boolean {
  return node.isComment && node.asyncFactory
}
```

This internal prop check appears to be prevalent at least in version 2.6.

Comment: `isAsyncPlaceholder` is exported in its module, but as far as I can tell it’s not made available to third party code (e. g. in [`dist/vue.js`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.11/dist/vue.js#L3742) it’s a plain `function`) – is there a way to use it?

Comment: @LucasWerkmeister You should be able to import it from [`vue/src/core/vdom/helpers/is-async-placeholder.js`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/helpers/is-async-placeholder.js). Note that it's a Typescript file, so you'll need a `ts-loader`.